# For statement in label Python Tkinter

Tags: python, facebook, loops, tkinter, label

I want to display all results from the dictionary from Facebook to label in Python with Tkinter library. Label displays only first or last record. I'm using for loop.
This is my code:

```py
def loopInLabel(self, newsfeedData):
    for item in newsfeedData:
        try:
            a = ("Name: " + item['name'] + '\n' + "Message: " + item['message'] + '\n' + "Description: " + item['description'] + '\n')
            return a
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

And dispaly in label

```py
def facebookEvent(self, label):
    newsfeed = F.get('/me/home', {'fields':'name,description,message'})
    newsfeedData = newsfeed["data"]
    label.config(text=self.loopInLabel(newsfeedData))
```

All is ok when I print it to the console with normal print()

Comment: Not sure if you know this already, but if you have a `return` inside a for loop, the loop will only execute once and then the function will end. That's why only your first news feed item is being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to display all of your news feed items at once in a single label, don't `return` inside the loop. Append the items to a list and return the whole thing when you're done.

```
def loopInLabel(self, newsfeedData):
    lines = []
    for item in newsfeedData:
        try:
            a = ("Name: " + item['name'] + '\n' + "Message: " + item['message'] + '\n' + "Description: " + item['description'] + '\n')
            lines.append(a)
        except KeyError:
            pass
    return " | ".join(lines)
```

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. I will remember your advices.